# Boost - Cannot open include file: 'ctype.h'

Tags: boost

I'm installing Boost 1.57.0 through the VS 2015 CTP6 Command Prompt, and I'm at the Boost.Build compile stage, but I get many of the below errors when running `tools\build\bootstrap.bat`:

```
e:\boost_1_57_0\tools\build\src\engine\jam.h(34): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'ctype.h': No such file or directory
```